# CodeIgniter get value from Max

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, trygetvalue

How to get value from MAX('table')?

This is the code

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [applicant_id] => A001
            [MAX(education_type)] => 6
        )
)
```

To get the value from 'applicant_id' i simply using this

```
foreach ($results as $row) {
echo "<td>";
echo $row->applicant_id;
echo "</td>";
}
```

but it is failed when i try to `echo $row->education_type;`
any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try this one?

```
echo $row->{"MAX(education_type)"}
```

Comment: thanks sadikhasan it's working, i need to improve my skill alot.-_- thanks

Comment: If you have satisfaction with this answer then accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

Provide a aliasing for `education_type` column in the query while fetching the  data.
I guess your query is now like this

```
select applicant_id,MAX(education_type) from table;
```

if you need to use `echo $row->education_type` in your code then change your query to

```
select applicant_id,MAX(education_type) as education_type from table;
```

Comment: yea this is working too but i'm using the code below, thanks anyway this is improve my knowledge